# How can I ensure my Azure web app is serving overseas customers 'fast enough'?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-web-app-service, saas

I tried to have this title as descriptive as possible. But I'm looking to offer a SaaS product to a company that has various 'sites' (physical sites) across many different countries.

Each country will have to have it's own DB stored in the closest Azure location, for compliance purposes. In either case, for compliance or not, they need a new DB - so I might as well have each site's DB in the most fitting location.

However, I'd prefer the DB to be the only thing that lives in different locations. This is a multi-tenanted system, my plan is for all UK subscriptions to go through the same web app service (.Net core Web API for what it's worth). This is fine, but for the company with overseas sites, **how could I decide whether, or not, I'll take a performance hit in running all requests through the same UK server as opposed to having to take a larger hit in profit by provisioning a web app service in each country?**

Are there some metrics I should be looking at? I am happy to bump up the spec of the web app service.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not going to be the performance of the web app, this will perform the same whether users are coming from the UK or Europe. The issue is the latency in users getting to your site, the further away from the user the application is, the more latency. If your storing the client's data in a database in their country then this is going to make things even worse, as now your web app needs to go off to the DB in another location before returning to the client. Again, no amount of app or DB size increase is going to help that.

The first thing you could do is to setup App Insights with your web application, this will provide you with lots of information about how long your DB queries are taking, slow client-side operations etc. You can see some basic examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/tutorial-performance).

Another thing you could look at is using Azure Front Door in front of your web app. This will add caching, and local points of presence to your app. So a user will hit a point of presence on the MS network close to them, they will then connect to your app over the MS backbone which should be faster than going over the internet.

Ultimately though, if your performance is not what you want for users outside of the UK then the only solution will be to create an instance of your web app close to them and their data.

Comment: Brilliant Sam! Thanks so much for this reply, I'd never heard of Azure Front Door. I'll look into it now, this is a big help.